# iOS - Color Space - Metal Texture to UI Image - iPhone vs iPad Camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, metal, image-conversion

I'm running into some inconsistency with image conversion in iOS.

In realtime, I'm grabbing frames from the camera, converting the pixel buffer to a metal texture, applying effects with metal shaders, viewing it in a metal view, populating the resulted texture in `renderedTexture`, then grabbing the final image from `renderedImage`.

The `MTKView` and a UIImageView with `renderedImage` looks exactly the same on my iPad, just what I want, but on my iPhone the `renderedImage` looks a lot brighter, like a gamma of 2.

Here's my metal texture to ui image code:

```
public var renderedTexture: MTLTexture?
public var renderedImage: UIImage? {
    guard let texture = renderedTexture else { return nil }
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: nil) else { return nil }
    guard let cgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent, format: CIFormat.RGBA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.linearSRGB)!) else { return nil }
    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: .up)
    return uiImage
}
```

I'm guessing the cameras have different color spaces?
Any way to find out what they would be?

Dose the `MTLTexture` contain the camera image buffers's color space as meta data?
Maybe I'm loosing the meta data in my image conversion?

My devices:
- iPad Pro
- iPhone X
both on iOS 12

Comment: If you suspect the issue is the camera color space, then the important part is how you grab frames and convert the pixel buffer to a Metal texture.

Comment: I think I wish it was the camera color space, but the metal render looks good, so it's probably in image conversion, or the metal texture keeps the color space as meta data somehow...

Comment: What if you omit the format and color space from the CGImage creation?

Comment: To answer the question in your edit: no, Metal textures don't encode an original color space. Metal textures have a pixel format, which describes the layout and a limited set of color spaces. Most pixel formats are linear RGB but some are sRGB. I would hope that `CIImage` takes the Metal texture's pixel format into account when rendering. (Well, it must to some degree, but I'm referring to the difference between RGB and sRGB.)